# looking for a way to count combinations of numbers and how many times they appear in different lists ( sets of 2 and up )

Tags: python, set, compare

I have an exercise i want your opinion on
i get a a list of lists each one in a different length that contains numbers
And i need to find out what is the largest combination (Set) of numbers that appear in the other lists ( i need to do it per list)

for instance :
in the array below , you can see that only 80 and 88 appear in both line 1 and line 3
but 93 94 122 167 appear in line 1 and line 2
so i need to return 80,88 once for line 1 and 93,94,122,167 once for line 2 and line 3

```
arr = [[3,8,24,26,42,44,54,70,79,80,81,88,90,96,97,101,102,118,
        124,125,130,134,141,147,158,164,170,171,174,175,184],
       [5,21,23,39,41,51,67,76,77,78,85,87,93,94,98,99,115,121,
        122,127,131,138,144,155,161,167,168,171,172,181],
       [16,18,34,36,46,62,71,72,73,80,82,88,89,93,94,110,116,
        117,122,126,133,139,150,156,162,163,166,167,176]]
```

at first i thought about making a set for each list / line and then comparing sets
but that seems to expensive especially since  the minimum set is 2 and the maximum in this example is 31

What would be a better way to compare the sets in each list?

For the record ,at first i wanted to do something like this per line :

```
import itertools

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  for length in range(0, len(arr)):
      for subset in itertools.combinations(arr, length):
```

I didn't actually write any code since i get this is very unoptimized

Edit , sorry if i was not clear i am looking for sets of 2 and above not just repeating numbers

Comment: both lines 1,2 contain 171, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: The rule of what to "count" is not clear. Please explain.

Comment: sorry i was not clear i need sets of 2 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.combinations` on `range(len(arr))` to create 2-combinations iterator. While iterating over it, create a dictionary that maps `arr[i]` to the set intersections.

Finally, use a dict comprehension to select the largest set for each sublist index and convert them to lists.

```
from itertools import combinations
tmp = {}
for i, j in combinations(range(len(arr)), 2):
    set_inter = set(arr[i]) & set(arr[j])
    tmp.setdefault(i, []).append(set_inter)
    tmp.setdefault(j, []).append(set_inter)
out = {k: list(max(v, key=len)) for k, v in tmp.items()}
```

Output:

```
{0: [80, 88], 1: [122, 93, 94, 167], 2: [122, 93, 94, 167]}
```

`max(v, key=len)` is finding the largest set (because `len(set)` returns its size)